# nmap delay defaulting to 1000000

Tags: nmap

I am running the below nmap command-

```
nmap -v -d8 -Pn -sT --scan-delay .25s ip_address
```

When I check the timing stats it seems the value for scan delay is defaulting to 1000000.

```
**TIMING STATS** (1.1248s): IP, probes 
active/freshportsleft/retry_stack/outstanding/retranwait/onbench, 
cwnd/ssthresh/delay, timeout/srtt/rttvar/
Groupstats (1/1 incomplete): 4/*/*/*/*/* 10.00/75/* 1000000/-1/-1
```

Can anyone please share their thoughts on this.

Comment: How are you checking the timing stats? and how do you determine that 1000000 is the value for the delay? I'm having trouble finding a definition for the debugging fields.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the scan delay is not shown in the "Groupstats" line of output. The fields marked with `*` are not available (or not relevant) for the group as a whole. They should have values in the next output lines, which show the stats for each host being scanned.

The `--scan-delay` option gets stored in the `o.scan_delay` field of the global `NmapOps` object. When each host is scanned, it keeps track of its own send delay (`HostScanStats::sdn.delayms`), which is initialized from the global `o.scan_delay`.

The `1000000` you see is part of the third group of fields, and is specifically the current `timeout` value in microseconds, equivalent to 1 second.

Comment: Do you have sources that point to where the definition of these values are?

Comment: @schroeder In the Nmap source code, the `--scan-delay` option is parsed in `nmap.cc`. The `sdn.delayms` is initialized in the `HostScanStats` constructor in `scan_engine.cc`. And the timing output is in `printAnyStats` in `scan_engine.cc`.